# Rails 3 - Is there any fallback for when serving assets from an asset server fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, cdn, fallback

In my `production.rb` I've set this:

```
# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://myassets.com"
```

And the images, js and stylesheets are loading fine from my CDN (assets server)

but what if someday this asset servers fails? and it returns a 404?

Because in my assets server (CDN) I have configure a `pull zone`, the content is still available from `/assets/..`.

Is there any fallback or how can I make a fallback so when my `assets server` fails or return error my application loads assets from `/assets/` inside the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

production.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request, asset_path|
  if some_condition
    "http://myassets.com"
  else
    asset_path
  end
}
```

For more info, see [AssetTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html)

**Edit**

I don't think this precaution is worth the extra load/added requests to your application. If you were building a large application with failover servers to provide high availability, assets would be yet another thing you'd accommodate for with that redundancy. If you're hosting your stuff on the cloud through a service like AWS or Rackspace, I think you're good on availability and you shouldn't worry about the issue. This approach almost completely negates the benefit of caching assets.

Comment: `asset_path` nice! now I use this to check if the can is still alive `uri = URI(url)` `res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)` `if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess) ...` but this one makes the application load slowly, is there another way around?

Comment: You're right, but what if there's a way to check asset server only once every load? application wouldn't run that slow I think... at this level I cannot use `sessions` what would be an option there?

Answer (score 0):

You might explore the following directive

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
  if #code to check if CDN is alive
    "CDN Url"
  else
    "/public/assets/"
  end
}
```

Comment: And this should go on my `production.rb` or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, can be under   config.action_controller.asset_host, make sure you put this as well.

Comment: Inside the `else` clause i return `"/assets"` but it tries to load the things from `http:///assets/...` and if i set the `else` to return `"http://localhost:3000/assets"` ... still nothing loads.